# wordpress if statement not responding

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

The website I am working on has a different footer on the home page to all the other pages on the site.
However the footer does not appear on any of the pages at all. 
here is the code I am using:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage 
?>

    <div id="footer"> This is home page</div>

<? } else {   ?> 

    <div id="footer">This is not a homepage</div> 

<?}?>
```

Is my syntax wrong? Why doesn't this code work?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things I can think of here:

1. You are using a static front page. In this case you will need to check for is_front_page()
2. Using `<?php` open tags

Consider revising the code to following:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page()) { ?>
    // This is a homepage 
    <div id="footer"> This is home page</div>
<?php } else {   ?> 
    <div id="footer">This is not a homepage</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I have tried the `<?php` and `is_frontpage()` but its still not working

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using an old version of php, you might want to switch `<? } else { ?>` to `<?php } else { ?>` - note that I'm using a `<?php` instead of just `<?`.

As for the `is_home()`, you might want to read up on the following link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

It seems as if `is_home()` sometimes isn't the same thing as `is_frontpage()`, which means that you in some cases need to use `is_frontpage()` instead.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I tried the `<?php ` and `is_frontpage()` but its still not working.

Comment: I must ask - where are you putting the code in your original post?

Answer (score 0):

Using `<?php` open tags is one of the "best practices" in WordPress coding. Also, consider using `<?php get_footer('footer-variant') ?>` instead of conditional statements in your footer.php. After calling `get_footer('my-footer')`, `footer-my-footer.php` file will be used.

Comment: thanks for your response `<?php get_footer('footer-variant') ?>` didn't work either.

Comment: You probably used it wrong way... Refer to documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer